# Swift 2.1 selector Swift 2.2 #selector

Tags: swift2

Swift 2.2のつもりで書いたソースコードです。

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, self, selector: #selector(ViewController.timeCheck(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)}
```

これでエラーになります。

Swift 2.1では出なかったエラーです。

下記のソースがSwift 2.1で出なかったソースです。

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("timeCheck:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

どこをどう直したらよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: どのようなエラーが出ていますか？エラーメッセージなど内容が分かる情報を載せてください。

Comment: Missingargumentlarget:’in call エラーメッセージです。

Comment: Missing argument larget:’in call

Answer (score 1):

載せていらっしゃるコードが書き間違いでなければ、`scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval()`メソッドの２番目の引数のラベルが抜けています。
引数ラベルのメソッドのシグネチャのうちなので、書き忘れると別のメソッドになってしまいます。

```
timer  = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.timeCheck(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

^ 上記のように`0.1, target: self, selector:...`と書く必要があります。

Comment: お陰様でエラーの２つは消えました。

Comment: もう１つエラーがあります。
 
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: selector: #selector(background_tap(_)))

Comment: UIGestureRecognizerのイニシャライザにselectorという引数はありません。正しくは→ `let tapGesture = UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.background_tap(_:))` だと思います。